# Find final height of UIWebView for vertical stacked layout

Tags: ios, dynamic, uiwebview, uiscrollview, height

I've got a UIView with several containers, each containing 4 items stacked vertically.

- UILabel - name1    (25px fixed, if present, 0px if not)
- UIWebView - desc1  (80px fixed to start, but dynamically adjusted for content)
- UILabel - name2    (25px fixed, if present, 0px if not)
- UIWebView - desc2  (80px fixed to start, but dynamically adjusted for content)

The UIWebViews contain a short bit of mixed text/html loaded locally in onViewDidLoad.  I'm adjusting the frame for each element after I attempt to find the dynamic heights of the webview, which works assuming the height found is accurate.  I adjust the size after the webviews have loaded.

I'm having a lot of trouble determining the dynamic height of them accurately however, and thus a lot of overlap is occurring.  Often the height is too small and the webview scrolls within its fixed height.

```
// resizeElements: adjusts all the frame heights/origins
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [self resizeElements];
}

// not really working at all
// have tried various other methods using html height, etc, etc.
-(float) getWebViewContentSize:(UIWebView*) myWebView{
    NSString *heightString = [myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.body.offsetHeight"];
    int heightInt = [heightString intValue];
    return heightInt;
}

// seems proportionate, but is about 20% too small for larger amounts of content usually
//    and increasingly too small the longer the text gets.
-(float) getWebViewContentSize2:(UIWebView*) myWebView{
    CGSize size = myWebView.scrollView.contentSize;
    int height = size.height;
    return height;
}
```

Any better ways to get height or suggestions on laying these 4 elements out otherwise?

Comment: Does the viewcontroller use autolayout?

Comment: No, autolayout is not used.  The basic pre-resized layout is in a XIB, and autolayout is disabled there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<del>had the same issue. cant still find any solution except calling resize function ([self resizeElements] is your case) with half second delay. 
when calling [myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.body.offsetHeight"] just after webViewDidFinishLoad: - document height is always equal to current webView frame height.
it ugly but it working</del>

<del>**EDIT:**  I spent half of hour more and  figured out that `[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.height;"]` working properly only if you set webView's frame before you're loading html string. And also important that size of frame must be greater then zero (e.g. `CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)`)</del> *this is not working fine*

**EDIT 2:** I spent one more hour and the final solution is:

layoutSubviews method looks like:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    CGRect actualFrame = self.view.bounds;

    _titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, actualFrame.size.width, 80);

    [self resizeWebview:_primaryWebView];
    _primaryWebView.frame = CGRectMake(0, _titleLabel.frame.origin.y + _titleLabel.frame.size.height,
                                       actualFrame.size.width, _primaryWebView.frame.size.height);


    _subtitleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, _primaryWebView.frame.origin.y + _primaryWebView.frame.size.height,
                                      actualFrame.size.width, 80);

    [self resizeWebview:_secondaryWebView];
    _secondaryWebView.frame = CGRectMake(0, _subtitleLabel.frame.origin.y + _subtitleLabel.frame.size.height,
                                         actualFrame.size.width, _secondaryWebView.frame.size.height);

}
- (void)resizeWebview:(UIWebView *)webView
{ 
    CGRect frame = webView.frame;

    frame.size.height = 1;
    webView.frame = frame;

    frame.size.height = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.height;"].floatValue;

    webView.frame = frame;
}
```

you can also get frame height from

```
CGSize sizeThatFits = [webView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
frame.size = sizeThatFits;
```

works equally with both methods.

and don't forget to resize webViews **after** they did load or did change orientation:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [self.view setNeedsLayout];
}

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    [self.view setNeedsLayout];
}
```

so, thanks to you, i refactored my code and finally got rid of that ugly time delay :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've tried it and it doesn't seem to make any difference if there is a delay.  It may be because it is a relatively small text blurb, loaded locally.  It also makes the already unfriendly UIWebView load delay a double whammy with a second resize delay.

Comment: I tried the new solution, but it the results are still off.  On a plus side: webView.scrollView.contentSize, stringByEvaluatingJavaScript, and sizeThatFits methods all return the same height.  It is just about 20% short still.  For whatever reason my approx 240px height test html string is coming back as 208px.. and thus about 2 lines of text are cut off, visible only by scrolling if it's enabled.

Comment: I will likely be going with a different approach than the UIWebView, but am curious why this doesn't work still.

Comment: its really strange, cuz as you can see I emulate code that you have described, and in my case everything works fine. so can you post anywhere your example of code with that HTML-text that you try to load, so I can explore it!

Comment: Thanks for your support.  When copying the detailed code into an edit and polishing it up for here, I'm embarrassed to say I find a math error that was likely causing this issue.  Your methods are working better now.

Comment: Calling setNeedsLayout isn't calling my viewDidLayoutSubviews in my controller. Is there something special you're doing? I'm trying to avoid this 0.5s delay as well, but can't find a solution.

Comment: @kevinl no, nothing special. Have you tried to call `layoutIfNeeded` in addition to `setNeedsLayout`? does it invoke `viewDidLayoutSubviews` then?